# Can't connect to device behind switch

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, ethernet, switch

probably it's a very simple question, but I'm not a network expert.
At home I have a modem router with WIFI + LAN (D-LINK DSL-2680), in another room I plugged a switch ([Netgear GS208](http://www.netgear.co.uk/home/products/switches-and-access-points/unmanaged-switches/200-300.aspx)) and then connected to it my XBOX and my Raspberry Pi (both with static IP). 
Well, with this configuration I can't even ping these two devices from my laptop using WiFI (I already checked and we are in the same IP class), but if I remove the switch everything works fine.

I checked on product page and they say I don't need a crossover cable, so my question is: what am I doing wrong?
I already tried to change ethernet ports, rebooting my router/switch and so on, but nothing works...

Comment: You stated "modem router w/WiFi + LAN" is this a single device or multiple devices i.e., modem, router/switch w/WiFi?

Comment: Try to do a MAC adress scan and check if  the switch is recognized.

Comment: @packets it's a single device with modem + router and it provides wifi access + it's connected to the LAN. The switch is another device

Comment: @ChristianGärtner can you give me more info about doing that? As I said, I'm not very experienced :/

Comment: Please include the make/model of your router.

Comment: Just google it there are plenty tutorials in the www. Keyword could be "mac adress scan" or "arp-scan"

Comment: @techie007 Added router model

Comment: *"if I remove the switch everything works fine"* -- So why are you introducing the switch? *"with this configuration I can't even ping these two devices from my laptop using WiFI"* -- Why do you need a switch to use WiFi?  *"I plugged a switch"* -- "Plugged" where? To what? Connected to the modem router?  Did you power up the switch?  Do any of the lights on the switch come on?  Have you tried to simplify the problem, i.e. reduce it down to fewer connections instead of laptop to XBox?  Cable the laptop to the switch and turn off WiFi; can you `ping` the router?